# How can I POST to a route and assign the values to a GET route?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to access planSchema in planDetailsSchema but I can't. Note both are on different routes. planDetailsSchema does not have a POST only a GET route which means the data from planSchema should be available to planDetailsSchema when a POST request is made to planSchema

###### planSchema

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export interface IPlan {
  planName: string;
  personalName: string;
}

const PlanSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IPlan>(
  {
    planName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide plan name"],
    },
    personalName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide personal name"],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model<IPlan>("Plan", PlanSchema);
```

###### planDetailsSchema

```js
import mongoose, { SchemaTypes } from "mongoose";
import { IPlan } from "./Plan";

interface IPlanDetails {
  planSchema: IPlan;
  status: "Processing" | "Active" | "Expired" | "Declined" | "Refunded";
}

const PlanDetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IPlanDetails>({
  planSchema: {
    type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: "Plan",
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: "Processing",
    enum: {
      values: ["Processing", "Active", "Expired", "Declined", "Refunded"],
      message: "{VALUE} is not supported",
    },
  },
});

export default mongoose.model<IPlanDetails>("PlanDetails", PlanDetailsSchema);
```

###### addPlan

```js
const addPlan = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const plan = await new Plan(...req.body);

  res.status(201).json({ plan });
}
```

###### getPlanDetails

###### which should include plans but it doesn't(GET only route)

```js
export const getPlanDetails = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const planDetails = await PlanDetails.find({}).populate("Plan");

  res.status(200).json({ planDetails });
};
```

The current output is

```
{
    "planDetails": []
}
```

It doesn't output the data which should have been shared with it and it doesn't output the default.

Comment: What is planName field in your schema? Is it a reference to another Mongoose model?

Comment: Yes, it is a reference to another Mongoose model
```ts
planName: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Plan"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the ref option to specify the target model.

```js
planName: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Plan', 
}
```

Also you haven't shown how you are adding data to the PlanDetails collection, so make sure that data is correctly inserted into the database.

Comment: The data added to the PlanSchema via route ```ts
"/api/v1/plan"
```
When added it is to be shared with PlanDetailsSchema which is on a separate route ```ts
"/api/v1/dashboard"
```
The first is a POST req, the latter is a GET req